# Why does nothing happen when I run this code?

Tags: python

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQoQ1.png)Can someone please explain to me why my code is not executing? Thank you in advance.

```
def fibonacci(n):
if n == 1:
    return 1
elif n == 2:
    return 1
elif n > 2:
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

for n in range(1, 11):
    print(n, ":", fibonacci(n))
```

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: Thanks again! I was tabbing instead of using spaces. It runs now.

Comment: Even though it can run - given the `recursive` approach, it is NOT efficient - eg. try to run `n` as '20` or more, see what's happening?

Comment: Do you mean this?

for n in range(1, 21):

Comment: Yes.  Are you familiar with this visual platform - https://pythontutor.com/ ?  Try to run it and see what's happening when your `n = 20`  first or `50`

Comment: No, I am not familiar with that visual platform. I will have a play around with it and run n as 50. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

You indentation is wrong. Indentation is very important in Python.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    elif n > 2:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

for n in range(1, 11):
    print(n, ":", fibonacci(n))
```

Comment: Thanks again! I was tabbing instead of using spaces. It runs now.

Comment: Even though this can run for small `n`, but it will fail of bigger `n`... due to exceed `recursive stack limit`.  (if you know what it means)